# Как программно декомпилировать resources.arsc?

Tags: java, android

Стоит задача, декомпилировать `resources.arsc` из apk чтобы достать `colors.xml`. Как это можно сделать программно? Это будет функция Android приложения

Comment: Ух... Да что же Вы вечно такими темными делами занимаетесь! То взламываете что-то, то декомпилируете! :D

Comment: Честно говоря, я таким никогда не занимался, но первая мысль - порыться в исходниках *apktool*. Может найдете что-то полезное - [исходники](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool)

Comment: @Rostislav Dugin, я делаю Theme Studio для Cyanogenmod прошивок. Идея заключается в вынимании цветов и предоставления пользователю их замены. Все вот продумал, начал делать и тут оказывается не протоптано :D

Comment: Если не секрет: для себя или работа в этом заключается? Да и Cyanogen закрылся, вроде бы?

Comment: @Rostislav Dugin, для себя и форума 4pda + в стор залью :) cyanogen закрылся, да, но не всем досталась линейка и еще масса народа сидит на неофициальном циане. Ну а вообще мне просто интересно это

Comment: Ну тогда удачи! :) Чуть не забыл Вам плюсик поставить...

Comment: Начиная с линейки движок тем пропал, если он не появится, то это меня не огорчит, я хочу сделать и пофиг что пользоваться будут мало (читай - вообще не будут).

Comment: Сходите на гитхаб с запросом apk parser.

Comment: @woesss я уже нашел приложение ShowJava с открытым исходным кодом, сделал git clone и скопипастил необходимые классы в проект. Сейчас немного допилю еще, выкину на гитхаб и оставлю ответ

Comment: Помню, баловался... Там только GUI свой, а вся декомпиляция на чужом коде. В том числе apk-parser и JaDX. И помнится мне JaDX более адекватен к именам и значениям в ресурсах, но он полноценный декомпилятор, поэтому "потяжелее" будет. Он тоже есть на гитхабе с открытым кодом.

Comment: @woesss, да, но я не понял как подключать его и решил собрать из исходников работающего приложения